# Quando é que as threads (Thread Pool) são inicializadas? - C#

Tags: c#

Eu tenho o seguinte código:

```
public void mainFunc()   {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    { 
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(funcThread), pto);
    }
    Thread.Sleep(2000) // Thread de teste.
    // Fazer algo quando todas as funcThread chegarem ao fim.
    // .....
    // Form4.doSomething()
}
```

Ou seja, eu quero que a `funcThread` seja criada 10 vezes e após todas as 10 funções chegarem ao fim, quero fazer uma rotina que chama outra Form. O que acontece é que primeiro ele executa tudo o que está na `mainFunc` e só depois ele faz o que está nas `threads`.

Eu já experimentei colocar um `Thread.Sleep` de 2 segundos, mas nem assim. Ele deixa passar os dois segundos, faz o que tem a fazer no form4 e só depois avança para as 10 threads...

Porque é que assim que faço o `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(funcThread),pto)` o programa não começa logo a executar as threads, mas só depois de terminar o mainFunc? Obrigado

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quando falamos em manipular Threads em C#, o recomendável é utilizar a [Task Parallel Library (TPL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-based-asynchronous-programming), que é uma API mais alto nível para manipular o ThreadPool da aplicação. E nem sou eu quem digo isso: a [própria Microsoft](https://web.archive.org/web/20160706175607/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/pfxteam/archive/2009/10/06/9903475.aspx) é quem recomenda porque eles perceberam o quão complicado era controlar algumas coisas através da biblioteca original:

> In conclusion, I’ll reiterate what the [CLR team’s ThreadPool developer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericeil/clr-4-0-threadpool-improvements-part-1) has already stated:

> **“Task is now the preferred way to queue work to the thread pool.”**

De qualquer forma, ao usar um **QueueUserWorkItem**, você está sugerindo que quando sobrar alguma Thread, ele vai executar um determinado método. O problema é que dessa forma, não temos controle sobre quando isso ocorrerá.

Através da TPL, basicamente temos a classe Task que representa uma operação assíncrona que pode ou não ter sido feita ainda. Dessa forma, no exemplo abaixo, eu mando a TPL executar 10 vezes uma operação e guardo a referência das Tasks para controlar suas execuções:

```
// utilizei um clique de botão só para testar, tanto faz aqui
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // só porque você definia ele como parâmetro do seu método
    int pto = 0;

    var taskList = new List<Task>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        // manda enfileirar no ThreadPool pra executar o seu método
        var task = Task.Run(() => { funcThread(pto); });

        // adiciona na lista a referência a cada Task criada
        taskList.Add(task);
    }

    // manda esperar que todas as Tasks referenciadas terminem para que o programa continue
    Task.WaitAll(taskList.ToArray());

    // espera uns 5 segundos só pra vermos o output confirmar o teste
    await Task.Delay(5000);

    // chama o seu form sem problemas
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} - Form4.doSomething()", DateTime.Now));
}

public void funcThread(int pto)
{
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} - funcThread", DateTime.Now));
}
```

A saída do meu exemplo:

```
09/02/2016 23:48:55 - funcThread
09/02/2016 23:48:55 - funcThread
09/02/2016 23:48:55 - funcThread
09/02/2016 23:48:55 - funcThread
09/02/2016 23:48:55 - funcThread
09/02/2016 23:48:55 - funcThread
09/02/2016 23:48:55 - funcThread
09/02/2016 23:48:55 - funcThread
09/02/2016 23:48:55 - funcThread
09/02/2016 23:48:55 - funcThread
09/02/2016 23:49:00 - Form4.doSomething()
```

**Observação**: só utilizei async/await no método para fazer a espera por 5 minutos, não é realmente necessário que seu método seja marcado como assíncrono para o **Task.WaitAll()** funcionar