# Iniciar várias threads em um comando de repetição

Tags: c#, .net, thread, multithreading

Tenho um projeto onde eu preciso iniciar 30 vezes uma *thread* que vai executar o mesmo método, e queria fazer isso em um comando de repetição, por exemplo:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
    { 
       Thread t = new Thread(MetodoVoid); 
       t.Start();
       System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
```

Mas quando uso isso diz que o *thread* já está em execução e da erro, como proceder?

Comment: Leia isto: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1946/101 Veja se algo mais abstrato não resolve melhor para você. Hoje há pouco motivo para usar *thread* bruto: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/77759/101 e http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2793/101 Veja isto também: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/86014/101 Também: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/112357/101

Comment: Este código funciona perfeitamente: https://dotnetfiddle.net/UCXSRv. O erro está em outro lugar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você está jogando tudo em uma variável só. Se quiser insistir nessa forma, tem que jogar elementos de um *array* ou lista, assim cada *thread* estará em uma variável.

Mas leia meu comentário. Se está errando em algo tão simples, não deveria usar algo que é tão complicado fazer certo.

```
var threads = new List<Thread>();
for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) { 
   threads.Add(new Thread(MetodoVoid)); 
   threads[i].Start();
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Other/CreateMultipleThreads.cs).

Comment: eu sei onde está meu erro, coloquei aquele código só pra ilustrar o que eu quero

Comment: eu pensei nessa de criar um array ou uma lista, mas ainda não consegui aplicar

Comment: ahahaha resolveu! muito obrigado cara =]

Comment: @LuísMiguel Isso não faz sentido. No seu código original, a cada iteração do loop a variável recebe uma nova instância de Thread, e o Start ocorre nesta nova instância - não vai dar erro de thread já em uso porque não está referenciando a mesma thread. O seu erro estava em outro lugar e não na reutilização da variável. O array não tá resolvendo nada aí. Não tem como "jogar  tudo em uma variável só" - uma variável só pode ter um único valor (no caso, o valor da variável é uma referência para a thread recém instanciada). Veja o seu código original funcionando ok: https://dotnetfiddle.net/UCXSRv

Comment: O erro é que o MétodoVoid não tinha terminado ainda antes de iniciar de novo, e eu queria eles funcionando de forma simultânea, por isso dava o erro.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Thread> lst = new List<Thread>();

for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
{
   lst.Add(new Thread(MetodoVoid));
}

lst.ForEach(t => t.Start());
```

Comment: tem como colocar um sleep nessa lambda?

Comment: Não tenho certeza nesse caso, sugiro então que faça um foreach convencional.

Comment: Colocar um `Sleep` depois do `Start()`? @LuísMiguel

Comment: é, tipo isso...